# Antlr4 contextSuperClass to add custom properties for a two pass interpreter

Tags: antlr4

I have just discovered `contextSuperClass` and have been experimenting with using it to provide scope annotations when building a symbol table in a first pass (I have a forward reference DSL).

I set the option in the grammar:

```
options {
    tokenVocab=MyLexer;
    language  = CSharp;
    contextSuperClass = interpreter.MyParserRuleContext;
}
```

and I have a class that derives from `ParserRuleContext`:

```
public class MyParserRuleContext : ParserRuleContext
{

    public MyParserRuleContext()
    { }

    public MyParserRuleContext(ParserRuleContext parent, int invokingStateNumber) : base(parent, invokingStateNumber)
    {
    }

    public IScope ContextScope { get; set; }
}
```

So far so good. I use `ParseTreeWalker` with a listener (Enter/Exit methods) to walk the tree for the 1st pass and build the symbol table adding local scopes, etc into my `ContextScope` custom property.

The first issue is of course after the symbol table pass I am at the end of the token stream - the tree is walked.

The 2nd parse uses a visitor to evaluate the final result.

I have two questions:

1. How do I "reset" the parser so that it is at the root again without loosing scopes I have added into my custom property?
2. The second question is broader, but similar. Is this even a reasonable way to add scope annotations to the parse tree?

I have previously tried to use `ParseTreeProperty<IScope>` to add scope annotations, but the problem is similar. During the 2nd phase, the context objects provided in the visitor are not the same objects added to `ParseTreeProperty<IScope>` concurrent dictionary from the 1st pass - so they are not found. Between the 1st & 2nd passes I have only found `parser.reset()` as a way to start the parser over, and (of course) it appears to fully reset everything and I loose the any state I created in the 1st pass.

I am likely missing completely missing something here - so any help to put me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you parsing twice? Does the 2nd parse depend on the symbol table?

Comment: Well that's the plan, to parse to build a symbol table, so forward references are present when the 2nd pass evaluates those references. I may well be confused about how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you planning on using semantic predicates (`{ .... }?`) to change the parse recognition for the second parse? I ask because it isn't clear still.

Comment: Apologies for the muddiness of the question - this could be a case of not quite understanding enough to be able to ask the right question. For semantic predicates as far as I know, then no - there is no requirement to alter the grammar at runtime. It is simply a case of needing to deal with forward calls to functions defined in later parts of code (within the same scope).

Comment: Then, in that case, I would recommend one parse and have two tree walkers after the parse (`ParseTreeWalker.Default.Walk(your-walker, your-parse-tree)`. I actually do the same for many of my tools). You can then decorate the parse tree using the walker as you describe using the superclass for the parse nodes. Or, you can skip superclassing the parse node type, create a `Dictionary<IParseTree, your-attributes-structure>`, and find the attributes from a parse tree node.